# Create Approximately Follows Distribution Symbol Using MathJax.

Tags: statistics, notation

I want to use MathJax to create an "approximately follows distribution" symbol. It is a tilde with a dot above and a dot below. The closest I get is $\overset{\cdot}{\underset{\cdot}{\sim}}$ but the distance from the bottom dot to the tilde is greater than the distance from the top dot to the tilde.

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the lower and raise command should give you a desirable result like this:
$\overset{\lower{0.5ex}{\cdot}}{\underset{\raise{1ex}{\cdot}}{\sim}}$.

Hope you find this useful, thanks!